# Chanting Gayatri mantra

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra, shloka, gayatri

I read that gayatri mantra should be learned from a sage or yogi OR Brahman. I want to start learning gayatri mantra. What is the procedure to follow for this and whom should I contact?

Comment: No one to contact if you have yagnopavit or your upnayana sanskara is done you can recite gyatri but rembember you have to follow some rules of conduct i.e. no drinking, eating meat, remaning bramhachari till marrige etc if you do not follow rules for gyatri you will have to face bad consequences. You have to do sandhyavandana for reciting gyatri https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhyavandanam also you should follow any one of grhiya sutras https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpa_(Vedanga)

Comment: not upnayana is done to me as I am not born under brahmin family. I don't know what yagnopavit is. I don't eat meat and don't drink.

Comment: Can non brahmans practice the Gayathri mantra by following the daily rituals mentioned above by Yogi? I belong to kshtriya. So How can I start the gayatri mantra without doing anything wrong. Please anyone answer this.

Comment: @Nash Gayatri can be done by all Dvijas (members of the first three castes).  So as a Kshatriya you can certainly chant Gayatri, but first you need to do the Upanayanam (sacred thread ceremony).  Upanayanam is not limited to Brahmins, it's supposed to be done by all Dvijas.

Comment: As keshav said gyatri can be done by initiated dwijas but there is age restriction for kshatriyas it is 21 years max and should be unmarried , there is no scope for upnayan after marrige.

Comment: As Yogi's mentioning is right adequate steps to be followed or it will lead to reverse effect.

Comment: People are having gayatri mantra as ringtone nowadays  which is a not a good sign at all.Strictly speaking Gayatri mantra should be told by a grihastha who wars yagnopaveeda and he voice should be within mouth. Even Brahmin ladies are not supposed to tell gayatri mantra. Gayatri mantra should be pronounced by giving the correct pause inbetween..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different views on this. However here is a view of this, a more liberal one.

## Can all Hindus chant Gayatri Mantra

The Gayatri Mantra is considered by saints as the Universal mantra, one that all can chant, regardless of caste or creed. A pure mind is of course a good pre-requisite to any Sadhana.

> A man can repeat Gayatri mentally in all states while lying, sitting, walking etc. There is no sin of commission and omission of any sort in its repetition. One should thus perform Sandhya three times with this Gayatri Mantra every day, in the morning, noon and evening. **It is the Gayatri Mantra alone that can be commonly prescribed for all the Hindus.** The Lord commands in the Vedas "Let one Mantra be common to all" "Samano Mantrah. " Hence the Gayatri should be the one Mantra for all the Hindus. "The secret lore of the Upanishads is the essence of four Vedas, while Gayatri with the three Vyahritis is the essence of the Upanishads. " He is the real Brahmin who knows and understands thus, the Gayatri. Without its knowledge he is a Sudra, though well versed in the four Vedas.
>
> There is no milk superior to cow's milk. Even so there is no Mantra superior to Gayatri. As Omkara or Pranava is for Sannyasins, so is Gayatri for Brahmacharis and householders. The fruits that are attained by meditation on Omkara can be attained by meditation on Gayatri. The same goal that is reached by a Paramahamsa Sannyasin can be reached by a **Brahmachari or a householder** by meditating on Gayatri.
>
> What is the meaning of Gayatri Mantra

It is about worshipping that Brahman that illumines all three worlds and asking Her to enlighten our intellects.

Swami Sivananda's translation of Gayatri Mantra:

> Om - Para Brahman; Bhur - Bhuloka (Physical Plane); Bhuvah - Antariksha Svah; Svarga Loka Tat - Paramatma Savitur; Isvara (Surya); Varenyam; Fit to be worshipped; Bhargo - Remover of sins and ignorance; Devasya - Glory (Jnana Svaroopa); Dheemahi - We meditate; Dhiyo - Buddhi (Intellect); Yo - Which; Nah - Our; Prachodayat - Enlighten.
>
> Let us meditate on Isvara and His Glory who has created the Universe, who is fit to be worshipped, who is the remover of all sins and ignorance. May he enlighten our intellect.

## How to chant the Gayatri Mantra:

Discipline and steadfastness is the key to success in any field, and this includes spirituality. All the best.

> Get up at 4 a. m. in Brahmamuhurta and start Japa and meditation on Gayatri (Panchmukhi or five-faced Devi seated in lotus flower), sitting on Padmasana, Siddhasana or Virasana, facing North or East. Burn incense in the room. In summer you can take a bath. In winter you can simply wash your face, hands and feet and do achamana only. Continue the Japa for two hours or more. Have another sitting at night between 7 and 8 p. m. Constantly feel that you are receiving light, purity and wisdom from Gayatri. This is important. Keep the image of the Gayatri at the Trikuti, the space between the eye-brows by closing the eyes and concentrate there, or keep the image in the lotus of the heart and concentrate there. You will have Darshan of Gayatri.
>
> It is better if you do Japa of Gayatri 3000 to 4000 times daily. Your heart will be purified rapidly. If you are not able to do this number, you can do 1008 times daily. If you find it difficult to do this number also, do at least 108 times daily, 36 times at sunrise, 36 times at noon, 36 times at sunset. There is special, mysterious spiritual force or wonderful magnetic power at Sandhi or junction of the time, sunrise and sunset. The mind will be elevated quickly. It will be filled with Sattva. Concentration will come by itself without any effort at this time. If you find it difficult to get up at Brahmamuhurta, get up before sunrise. That man who fails to do Gayatri at the Sandhis fails in the discharge of his daily duties. He becomes a Bhrashta or fallen man. He loses vigour, vitality and Brahma-tejas.

## Spiritual Benefits of reciting Gayatri Mantra:

Gayatri Mantra, is considered as a very pure mantra with tremendous powers.

> The mind is purified by constant worship. It is filled with good and pure thoughts. Repetition of worship strengthens the good Samskaras. "As a man thinks, that he becomes. " This is the psychological law. The mind of a man who trains himself in thinking good, holy thoughts, develops a tendency to think of good thoughts. His character is moulded and transformed by continued good thoughts. When the mind thinks of the image of Gayatri during worship, the mental substance actually assumes the form of the image. The impression of the object is left in the mind. This is called Samskara. When the act is repeated very often, the Samskaras gain strength by repetition, and a tendency or habit is formed in the mind. He who entertains thoughts of Divinity becomes transformed actually into the Divinity himself by constant thinking and meditation. His Bhava or disposition is purified and divinised. The meditator and the meditated, the worshipper and the worshipped, the thinker and the thought become one and the same. This is Samadhi. This is the fruit of worship or Upasana.

**REFERENCE:** All the quotes are from [Gayatri Japa by Sri Swami Sivananda](http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1087)

**NOTE:** The rules of any sadhana are that one practices discipline and auterity at least to a certain extent before practicing other types of sadhana. Fire when controlled will be useful but when out of control, will burn us. Similarly the mantra siddhis obtained by such sadhanas, when done with a pure heart, pure mind and pure intellect, will confer auspiciousness and be of benefit to the society, but when used improperly, will lead to one's own downfall!

Thus in conclusion, we can say that Gayatri Mantra is the King of all mantras, and leads to complete Unity with God.

All the best!

Comment: @Nash Glad that your question has been clarified. I am in no way creditable for this as I simply posted what the great Mahatma Sri Swami Sivananda said. All the best in your spiritual search and hope all your doubts are cleared eventually!

Comment: "we can say that Gayatri Mantra is the King of all mantras". Isn't AUM the most ultimate mantra? Swami Vivekananda said, AUM is not a word, it is god himself.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Good point. "AUM is God Himself", says Swami Vivekananda. :) So technically you can't compare the two. Just see what the first word of Gayatri Mantra is: 'AUM'. All mantras are usually preceded by Aum, to imply the importance of Aum. Aum is the cosmic vibration that pervades all of Creation, isnt it. So I would say that it is not possible to compare Aum to another mantra, for such mantra is itself encompassed by Aum. Aum is Brahman Himself, says Mandukya Upanishad. All the best.

Comment: Yeah so what is the need to chant another mantra? What extra benefit will Gayatri Mantra bring?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Good question. It is all part of God's Leela. No two people are alike. Everyone is different. It is like asking 'Why should I go to a temple if God is everywhere'. If you feel truly satisfied chanting AUM and are able to feel the divine vibration, then there is no need for Gayatri Mantra. Similarly, if you are always happy and convinced that you are God already, then there is no need for even chanting AUM! It is a question of acceptance. Ramakrishna Paramahamsa said in the Gospel that 'The Sandhya merges in the Gayatri, the Gayatri merges in the AUM'. So no extra benefits. :)

Answer (score 3):

In my POV the mantra can be chanted by any one from Bhuloka Bhuvah Svah loka. By a Brahmachari or a householder by meditating on Gayatri. Like Mohamantra its a exempt from Ari Mantra. Any one can Chant Mohamantra, Gayatri Mantra of Rigveda, Om Namha Shivaya, Om TatSat etc.

Please check more info from Pt. Sanjay Rath Book's Vedic Remedies in Astrology of Mantra Sastra Chapter.

If you have any doubt about the mantra be sure its suites (check the akathaha cakra for suitability of a mantra) you and gives the positive result. For any Mantra you can concatenate an ātma bīja from both side of mantra.

Gayetri Mantra is exempt so you can chant it but you have to follow some codes of conduct please do not consume beef i.e. eating meat, no alcohol etc. Because its a Swastika mantra and these thing will make attenuation so the result will be less fruitful.

For Atma Bija you can refer to this Article 
http://www.manblunder.com/2012/09/how-to-derive-atma-bija.html

Contact ravi@manblunder.com

Comment: Please visit this website for more details : http://mantrashastra.net/mantra-sastra/mantra-foundation/mantra-theory/mantra-rules/